# Unable to delete all upper characters in a string

Tags: java

I am unable to delete all my upper case characters in my string. Any insight is appreciated.

if I input MANDY as str, I get output as AD. I am not sure why it is has this behavior.

```
StringBuilder outString = new StringBuilder(str);
for(int i = 0; i<outString.length(); i++){
    if(Character.isUpperCase(outString.charAt(i))){
        outString.deleteCharAt(i);
    }
}
return outString.toString();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By deleting the characters you change the indexes, so every uppercase character after another is not deleted.

A simple "trick" is to iterate the buffer the other way around (starting at the end). That way you only affect the indexes of already processed characters

```
for(int i = outString.length()-1; i>=0; i--){
    if(Character.isUpperCase(outString.charAt(i))){
       outString.deleteCharAt(i);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using `regex`:

```
String s = "MANDYs";
s = s.replaceAll("[A-Z]", "");
System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score -1):

You are increasing index while you are deleting items from the String you are iterating. I would call it a case of Concurrent Modification, though StringBuilder doesn't give any exception.

Better is to do this:

```
    int i = 0;
    while (i < outString.length()) {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(outString.charAt(i))) {
            outString.deleteCharAt(i);
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
```